# How do i access the Phabricator Maniphest restful APIs?

Tags: web, phabricator, task-management, maniphest

I'm trying to programmatically create tasks/bugs on Maniphest: https://www.phacility.com/phabricator/maniphest/

but i can't quite seem to find a RESTful API that can do this.

am i totally missing out on something? or does there not currently exist one

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660771/phabricator-get-commit-author-from-feed-story-for-stories-that-are-concerns-co/27864394#27864394

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Conduit (https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/conduit/) should work for you. There is a method called createtask (looks like https://secure.phabricator.com/conduit/method/maniphest.createtask/) that is exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can access phabricator's api, to create task ,query user info etc.

here is the demo for access https api by postman .

Note: for multi value field such as "ccPHIDs" , you should use format like the image. 
[image]

but in conduit UI Test. you have to use json format, like this: ["PHID-PROJ-xxx3", "PHID-PROJ-xx12"]

phabricator's API is the wrost api set, I have used by now. so sick...